# What is the point to use autolayout, grid view etc.?

Tags: ios, macos, autolayout

As far as I know, autolayout is only supported by iOS 6 and OS X 10.8. There are a lot of people with devices running iOS 5 (thank god people released jailbreak for 6.0, so people will update to the new version) and OS X 10.7. So what's the point to use new features NOW if therefore we throw out a whole bunch of users or need to support them by workarounds (manual layout, separate XIBs, SMGridView, SVPullToRefresh)?

Also where can I find the iOS/OS X distribution for now (as it done on the [Android site](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html))?

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's wrong for Apple, or any company for that matter to ever update their frameworks to improve them or add features?

Comment: @0x7fffffff No, I don't. I don't know if I miss something and there is an easy way to support new features on both platforms, or even should I support iOS 5 now. On the other hand, there is a JAR to support the Fragments API on old Android phones, why there is no support for dramatic changes on old iOSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that in most cases you want to target the lowest possible version of iOS (in a reasonable sense) that would still allow for you to develop a great app and also allow you to gain the most # of downloads.

That being said, iOS6 did offer up quite a few enhancements - Flow Layout etc. If the enhancements are not worth the workarounds, your best bet would be to target a lower version of iOS and forgo these newer features.

So I guess in a nutshell, I would recommend that at this point in time it may be best to target something like iOS 5 and not worry about auto layout.

The second part of your question - iOS Distribution stats - I dont believe any such metrics exists within the official Apple Developer site. Your best bet might be to search for stats published by the developer of some popular app - Here's an example: http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/